# MySQL what is the purpose of MAX(IF()) in these queries?

Tags: mysql

this is my first question asked here.

I'm relatively new to SQL and have seen a few times the usage of MAX(IF(condition, value1, value2)) in which value1 and/or value2 are not columns and I just cant understand what it is doing. From my understanding, the MAX function returns a single value which is the biggest value in a column or set of values(which can be interpreted as a column) but in these situations the values given to the MAX() function are not always columns and the utility of the MAX function just doesn't seem clear to me, especially since the output is often being taken as a column.

here are a few examples of the usage I don't understand:

EX1: the one seen in here->
[Performance in MYSQL , MAX( IF( condition ) ) or Subquery condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419539/performance-in-mysql-max-if-condition-or-subquery-condition)

EX2:

```
SELECT
   id_candidate,
   MAX(IF(situation = 'hired', '9999-01-01', '9999-01-02') AS date
FROM
   processes
```

I have tested a bit to see if i could understand but a few things got me even more confused:

1- if a single value is given as a column, the returned table will contain a column in which all rows have the value given;

2- but if MAX('value') is given as a column such as "date", for example, a single row will be returned with the value given in the date column and no clear relation between the row and the fact that it was chosen over any other, but the row returned is always the same as long as the value is the same.

I have found no material explaining this and I don't know if I'm supposed to already know this or what but I'm just completely lost here.

Comment: Are you sure there's no `GROUP BY id_candidate` at the end?

Comment: `MAX()` will return the largest *value* within that column or set of values. That means `MAX(situation)` will return the largest value in the `situation` column, but `MAX(IF(situation = 'hired', '9999-01-01', '9999-01-02'))` will return the largest value of the expression `IF(situation = 'hired', '9999-01-01', '9999-01-02')`. This expression, in turn, evaluates to either '9999-01-01' or '9999-01-02', depending on whether `situation = 'hired'` for each row.

Comment: Barmar, Some of the ones I found do have '''GROUP BY''' at the end, but I had not understood enough to connect the dots on the relevance of that yet. Good observation!

Answer (score 0):

The queries you showed have syntax errors or are at least badly written. There are columns which are not in a `GROUP BY` expression but in the list after `SELECT` and aren't applied to an aggregation function in that list. In almost all DBMS this isn't allowed. Older versions of MySQL or badly configured instance of MySQL do allow this. But the results might be random. So it should be avoided there too.

But that said...

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if):

> - `IF(`***`expr1`***`,`***`expr2`***`,`***`expr3`***`)`
>
>   If ***`expr1`*** is `TRUE` (***`expr1`*** <> 0 and ***`expr1`*** <> `NULL`),
>   [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if)
>   returns ***`expr2`***. Otherwise, it returns ***`expr3`***.

The expressions can be columns but they do not have to. They can be arbitrary (scalar) expressions.

Now when `if()` is nested in `max()` first `if()` is applied to each row (that satisfies the `WHERE` clause, if there's one), so there's one expression for each row, that `if()` returned for that row. `max()` then takes the maximum of the values the expressions evaluate to for each row.

Let's take a look at your example, `max(if(situation = 'hired', '9999-01-01', '9999-01-02'))`: `if(situation = 'hired', '9999-01-01', '9999-01-02')` will evaluate to `'9999-01-01'` for all rows where `situation = 'hired'` and `'9999-01-02'` for all the other rows. Then `max()` takes the maximum of `'9999-01-01'` and `'9999-01-02'` if both values are present (If only one value is present it can only take that one value of course.)